# Cannot find require path to custom module

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, path

I am trying to create a chatbot for a VoIP solution using NodeJS, I recently refactored all conversation handlers in their separate scripts for ease of reading on the entry point.

Those conversation handlers are structured as follows:

```
// foobar.js
const Help = require('.../utils/Help.js');
const Utils = require('.../utils/Utils.js');
const UserList = require('.../database/Users.json');

module.exports = {
    conversation: (message) => {
        // Code here
    }
    // other cool methods
}
```

This is what my folder architecture looks like: (important files are *marked*)

```
/chatbot
  /src
    /bin
      /conversation
          *foobar.js*
          foobarbar.js
          etc.js
    /database
      *Users.json*
    /utils
      *Help.js*
      *Utils.js*
    /node_modules
```

To me, it seems like I target the files I require correctly, however, on runtime, I am greeted with a splendid error

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '.../utils/Help.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:603:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Library\Documents\AIScroll\src\bin\conversation\foobar.js:1:76)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:733:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
```

No matter how many dots I put in `.../utils/Help.js`, I always have the same error. Whether there is only one or there are fifteen.
I bet it's a really silly mistake, too.
Cheers ahead of time ♪

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`./` = Current folder 
`../` = One folder up 
`../../` = Two folders up and so on...

So your code needs to be as follows:

```
const Help = require('../../utils/Help.js');
const Utils = require('../../utils/Utils.js');
const UserList = require('../../database/Users.json');
```

Multiple dot's wont work. It's always either `./` or `../`. 
You can however write `../` multiple times.

Comment: I confirm, this is working. As expected, a really silly reason. I'll keep that in mind in the future, thanks for the heads-up :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be `../../utils/Help.js` etc.

The `utils` folder is 2 directories up

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to get up to 2 levels:

```
const Help = require('../../utils/Help.js');
const Utils = require('../../utils/Utils.js');
const UserList = require('../../database/Users.json');
```